# What are the names of colors of lines in R-plotly?

Tags: r, plotly, r-plotly

I'm setting manually the color of lines in plot using plotly. I would like to know which are the names of the colors available to use.

I already know the names of the "basic" colors.

As: c("red","blue","green", "yellowgreen",...)

```
library(dplyr)
library(plotly)
library(magrittr)


color_line = "yellowgreen"

mtcars %>% count(gear) %>%
  plot_ly() %>%
  add_trace(x = ~gear, y = ~n, name = "Gear",type = "bar") %>%
  add_trace(x=~gear, y= ~cumsum(n/sum(n)), type ="scatter",mode="markers+lines" ,
            line=list(shape="spline", color = color_line), 
            marker = list(color = ""), 
            name = "Cumsum",yaxis = "y2") %>%
  layout(yaxis2 = list(tickfont = list(color = color_line),
                       overlaying = "y",
                       side = "right"
                        )
        )
```

Does someone know all the names of colors?

Greetings all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Here](https://www.r-graph-gallery.com/121-manage-colors-with-plotly/) is a full list of named colors:

https://www.w3.org/TR/css-color-3/#svg-color

Comment: That's great,

Best regards.

Comment: link is now broken?

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to use the names, from plotly's docs:

> a color may be specified as:
>
> - A hex string (e.g. '#ff0000')
> - An rgb/rgba string (e.g. 'rgb(255,0,0)')
> - An hsl/hsla string (e.g. 'hsl(0,100%,50%)')
> - An hsv/hsva string (e.g. 'hsv(0,100%,100%)')
> - A named CSS color

I'm not a design expert so whenever I need to choose colors I pick them from a palette or from the picker at [htmlcolorcodes](https://htmlcolorcodes.com/). They have a lot of info on how to choose colors also.